# Android studio not catching value from editText box

Tags: java, android, firebase

I would like to compare the Id that the user has inputted with the Id from the database as a login process. However, when I run the code after filling all the ID and password, the application returns that inputted ID and inputted pw are empty. What's the problem?

Comment: Once you correct for the suggested answers you'll find your treatment of the Firebase access is not sufficient.  This is because the `onDataChange` happens asynchronous to the button onclick so the `userId` and `userPw` will not be set as expected.  Suggest moving the comparison logic inside of the `onDataChange`.

Comment: And for help with what @Andy has said, you can have a look at this here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your encouragement!! what should I do if I see V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1, V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service while debugging :((

Comment: I'd estimate that error can be ignored; "FA" is Firebase Analytics which runs background threads and is simply being noisy about its routine activities.

Comment: @purplecherry It isn't a good practice to change the question adding another question. In this way the community doesn't see it and nobody answer the 2nd question. I suggest you closing the 1st question accepting the best answer (this indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution, there is no obligation to do this) and opening another question with the new code and the new question.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because

```
final String inputId = editId.getText().toString();
final String inputPw = editPw.getText().toString();
```

These strings are initialized **at the beginning** in the `onCreate()` method.

When you click the button the `buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener` is executed with the same values initialized (empty values).
You have to get the new values from the `EditText` views.

```
buttonLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        //...
        String user = editId.getText().toString();
        String psw = editPw.getText().toString();
        //..
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(psw)){ ... }
      }
    });
```

As mentioned by @Andy in the comments, you have to change also the check on firebase because the method is asynchronous.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user)&& TextUtils.isEmpty(psw)){ 
   Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Complete all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    //Firebase check
    ....
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //....
        //Check the values here
        if (userId.equals(inputId)) && userPw.equals(inputPw)){...}
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved the codes just above the if clause and debugged my application. It says: 

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14830 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8605', transport: 'socket'

Is it because the codes crash?

Comment: It is not related to the code. It seems that AS can't connect to debug device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value from the edit text after the text has been updated:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editId.getText().toString())&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(editPw.getText().toString()))...
```